# How to uninstall .net framework 5.0 from using Visual Studio Installer even when it is unchecked?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I needed to upgrade .net sdk to version 6.0 and for the same I need to uninstall any previous version which is already installed in the system (.net sdk 5.0.414 in this case). It shows that both .net sdk 5.0 and .net sdk 6.0 package is installed as shown in the control panel. But when I try to uninstall it via control panel it guides me to uninstall using Visual studio installer. But again in the VS installer it is found that the .net 5.0 runtime is unselected (which would probably mean that the package is no longer installed in the system).
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewgso.jpg)

Tried checking the box and clicking on modify it leads to downloading and installing.

Comment: So tick it to get it installed again, then untick to get it removed.

Comment: You do not need to unistall .net SDK 5.0 when you want to use .NET SDK 6.0. You can have as many versions installed as you want (although I would recommend to have only one SDK for each major version installed)